# Is it possible to list column entry only once?

Tags: mysql

While this is not a huge deal, I'm just wondering if this is possible (I'm using MySQL in case that matters).

I have a query that returns something like this:

```
Basket      Contents
basket1     apple
basket1     orange
basket1     pear
basket2     lemon
basket2     banana
basket2     lime
```

Is it possible using only SQL to get this output?

```
Basket      Contents
basket1     apple
            orange
            pear
basket2     lemon
            banana
            lime
```

In other words, is it possible to list the column entry only once for each entry?  Thank you.

Comment: you can use group concat for this.ex:select column1,group_concat(column2) from table group by column1;

Comment: Some things are easier to do in a client language than in SQL.

Comment: Can you explain what this requirement is for?  I'm suspicious that you're trying to work around something where there might be a better way.

Comment: I agree with Rick, this is presentation and should be dealt with outside the database.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is easier on the representational layer but if you want it in pure MySQL this will do it:

```
set @current='';
select show_basket, content 
from (
    select case 
        when @current = basket 
            then '' 
            else basket 
        end as show_basket, 
        content, @current:=basket 
    from test_131547
    order by basket
) a;
```

Output:

```
+-------------+---------+
| show_basket | content |
+-------------+---------+
| 1           | lemon   |
|             | lime    |
|             | apple   |
|             | banana  |
| 2           | kiwi    |
|             | apple   |
|             | orange  |
+-------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this code but something like this might work. Essentially the idea is getting a count of the occurrences of each basket "Basket" field. If it is 1 then show basket, if it has been seen before, display an empty string.

```
SELECT basket, 
       contents 
FROM   (SELECT IF(num <= 1, basket, "")                 AS Basket, 
               contents                                AS Contents, 
               (SELECT Count(*) 
                FROM   tbl1 t2 
                WHERE  t2.basket = t1.basket
                       ) AS num 
        FROM   tbl1 t1) AS tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The row number over partition numbers the basket groups starting at 1. Anything other than 1 would be a duplicate basket name and therefore display null.

```
 SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.Basket ORDER BY t.Basket ) <> 1
             THEN NULL
             ELSE t.Basket
        END Basket ,
        t.Contents
 FROM    MyTable AS t;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support row_number()

Comment: @Julien .... yet ;)

Comment: Ok, i tried that query against a linked mysql database and it worked so I assumed it was supported.